# java Introspector does not find static property or actually static getter/setter method?

Tags: java

I wrote a method using Java Introspector, but I found that it does not work when the setter/getter method is static！

```
public class Bean {

    public static String foo;

    public String bar;

    public static String fooBar;

    public static String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public static void setFoo(String foo) {
        Bean.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public String getFooBar() {
        return fooBar;
    }

    public void setFooBar(String fooBar) {
        Bean.fooBar = fooBar;
    }
}
```

And

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(Bean.class);
        PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
        for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors){
            System.out.println(propertyDescriptor.getName());
        }

    }
```

The code above runs return as below：

```
bar
class
fooBar
```

It only returns bar and `foorBar`

Does it mean Introspector does not find static properties or actually `getter/setter` method?

Answer (score 2):

Print out the `propertyDescriptor` object instead of it's name you can see that it looks at the methods on the bean class.

The Javadoc says:
If we don't find explicit BeanInfo on a class, we use low-level reflection to study the methods of the class and apply standard design patterns to identify property accessors, event sources, or public methods

So presumably "standard design patterns" means non-static accessors.  That is, it looks for `public void setXXX(T)` and `public T getXXX()` methods.

Comment: thanks for that; is my problem .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/40852452/294884 related ??