# Android, couldn't make static getter setter property work?

Tags: java, android, properties, getter-setter

I was trying this ...

```
public class Info {
    private static Info ourInstance = new Info();
    public static Info getInstance() { return ourInstance; }

    private static int currentIndex;

    public static void setCurrentIndex(int i) {
        Log.d("DEV", "setter!");
        currentIndex = i;
        // do other work here
    }

    public static int getCurrentIndex() {
        Log.d("DEV", "getter!");
        return currentIndex;
    }

    private Info() {
        Log.d("DEV", "class initialized no problem...");
        currentIndex = 42; // just doesn't work, only sets the field
    }

}
```

in any other class...

```
Info.currentIndex = 666; // just doesn't work
```

It just doesn't work - what could the problem be?  Tried everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you define the setter/getter if you are going to end up doing this?

```
Info.currentIndex = 666;
```

if so, then change **currentIndex** visibility to public...

or even better, be congruent with the code and do

```
Info.setCurrentIndex(666);
```

Comment: holy - I totally forgot that java doesn't give you magic access to the getter/setters.  Sorry for the time waste!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thanks!!!!!!!!!